# MailParser, stop after headers have been parsed

Tags: node.js

I am using [MailParser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) to parse incoming mail. It's done in two steps:

1. analyze (figuring out what to do with the email) and
2. handing it in several different ways depending on analysis result.

For analyze step I do not need to have any of the bodies or attachments parsed, just headers.

MailParser has this handy event:

```
mailparser.on("headers", function(headers) {
    console.log(headers.received);
})
```

Is there any way to break execution here? There's no need for MailParser to spend any CPU cycles after this point in my use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at their source code right now and they did not implement a way to do so, have a look at their [_process function](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser/blob/master/lib/mailparser.js#L197).

Because it is asynchronous, when you receive the `headers` event, it might already be further down the processing flow of `mailparser`.

What you could do though is fork their code and add a hook that pauses the flow when the headers are parsed, and continues only if your hook allows it to, which should not be too hard.

If you manage to do it in a clean way and add some tests for it, you could also open a pullrequest to them as I'm sure it could be useful to some other people as well!

You could also manually parse the headers before passing the envelope to `mailparser`, as the headers are separated from the body by a `\r\n\r\n` it is easy to find and parse those.